# Convert(change) current DateTime as per culture in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

```
if (!IsPostBack && !Page.IsCallback)
{
    double OffsetHrs = GetTimeZoneOffsetFromCookie();
    string dateFormat = ServiceManager.LocalizationService.GetString("AppHeaderTop", "DateFormat", "g");
    CultureSelected CultureSelected = GetCultureSelected();
    ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-OffsetHrs).ToString(dateFormat);                
if (CultureSelected.CultureCode != "en-US") 
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
    DateTimeFormatInfo currentDtfi = new CultureInfo(CultureSelected.CultureCode, false).DateTimeFormat;
    ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text, usDtfi).ToString(currentDtfi.ShortDatePattern); //what can i Use here ?
}
```

Let say Output of `ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text`
 for `en-US` culture is `11/2/2015 4:14 PM (70)`
If I select specific culture I want this datetime `11/2/2015 4:14 PM (70)` to appear in that specific culture format.

Comment: Avoid `Convert.ToDateTime`, use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead.

Comment: If i use DateTime.ParseExact how can do I represent " format" for different cultures. what could be the syntax for using different culture..??

Comment: @virtualreality That depends on the string and culture settings. For example culture has to be `PM` in it's  `PMDesignator` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems unclear but I try to give a shot.

First of all, what is this `(70)` exactly? Where is this came from? `en-US` culture *can't* parse this string without using it in a string literal delimiter with `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` methods. On the other hand, since you assing `ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text` the result of the `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-OffsetHrs).ToString(dateFormat)` code, I don't believe this `(70)` part is *really* an issue on this question.

Second, If I understand clearly, the problem seems the usage of `DateTime.ToString(string)` method.

```
ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text, usDtfi)
                                   .ToString(currentDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
                                    // ^^^ Problem seems here
```

Okey let's say you successfully parse this `ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text` with `usDtfi` culture (which is `en-US`), **but** with this `.ToString(string)` method, you are not using `currentDtfi` settings actually, you are using [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) settings when you generate formatted string representation of your `DateTime`.

From [`DateTime.ToString(String)` doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   string representation using the specified format and the formatting
>   conventions **of the current culture**.

Since we don't know what `GetCultureSelected` method returns exactly, it *may* or *may not* be the same culture with `currentDtfi`.

I *strongly* suspect, you can solve this problem to using *that* culture as a second parameter in `ToString` method as;

```
ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text, usDtfi)
                                   .ToString(currentDtfi.ShortDatePattern, currentDtfi);
```

IF this `(70)` is really part of on your string, you need to `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` methods to supply exact format of it.

```
string s = "11/2/2015 4:14 PM (70)";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/d/yyyy h:mm tt '(70)'", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = dt.ToString(currentDtfi.ShortDatePattern, currentDtfi);
}
```

Comment: Yes. As you said the problem lies ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text, usDtfi)
                                   .ToString(currentDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
                                    // ^^^ Problem seems here..................................                          When I am using that it is converting 11/3/2015 9:14 AM  to 03/11/2015. Time is not being displayed....And we don't have to worry about (70).

Comment: @virtualreality Because you are using `ShortDatePattern` of your `CurrentCulture` which is _only_ display date part. What do you want as a result exactly on your `ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text`?

Comment: @virtualreality Then you need to use custom format as `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` instead of `ShortDatePattern` like; `Convert.ToDateTime(ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text, usDtfi).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm")`

Comment: I am using culturecode here because I have more than one culture like "en-US",en-GB,it-IT,tr-TR and many more. Is there any other format or datepattern which can handle any culture datetime format.

Comment: if (CultureSelected.CultureCode != "en-US") {
                    DateTime datetimenow = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-iOffsetHours).ToString(dateFormat));
                    ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = datetimenow.ToString(new CultureInfo(CultureSelected.CultureCode));                
                }
I tried above code it is changing as per culture but I am getting seconds also ..for "en-GB" something like this 03/11/2015 10:27:00
and for "pt-PT" 03-11-2015 10:29:00.. How can I get rid of seconds? IF not is there any other way ?

Comment: @virtualreality Because you are using `ToString(IFormatProvider)` without any format. That's why it generates with `G` standard date and time format which is combination of `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern`. You **have to** specify your format explicitly as `ASPxLabelCurrentTime.Text = datetimenow.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm"));`